# Typescript nameof generic type T as property

Tags: angular, typescript, generics, typescript-generics

Is it possible to use the type of the parameter T in a class/interface as a property name?

```
export interface ISample<T> {
  nameof(T)      : T;  <-- this property should have the name of the type T nameof(T)
  otherProperties: any;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
const data: ISample<Houses>() = <something to construct the object>
console.log(data.houses)
```

So `houses` is a property of `data` that was generated by the interface.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is a structural type system. That is, the type system is concerned with structures, not names, and types may not necessarily have a name, let alone a unique one.

For instance, suppose you were to write:

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
}

interface Street {
  name: string;
}
```

is

```
ISample<{name: string}>
```

supposed to have a `person` or a `street` property?

So no, what you're asking for doesn't exist.

You'll probably want to declare:

```
interface PersonSample {
  person: Person;
}

interface StreetSample {
  street: Street;
}
```

or

```
interface Sample<T> {
  sample: T;
}
```